# Javascript pick values only from first row in the table

Tags: javascript, php

I am printing results from a database in to a table. Then I need to use them up and I use javascript.
I also use PHP to retrieve values from the database and print them in the table.

```
<table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr class="bg-teal-300">
            <th>Br.</th>
            <th>Materijal</th>
            <th>Tezina</th>
            <th>Boja</th>
            <th>Količina </th>
            <th><center><i class="ion-ios-cart-outline" style="font-size:18px; color:white;"><center></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php while($r=$q->fetch()){ 
            $id_print = $r['Id'];
            ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?='R-'. $r['Id']?></td>
            <td><?=$r['Material']?> </td>
            <td><?=$r['Quantity']?></td>
            <td><?=$r['Color']?></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity" placeholder="" ></td>
            <td><center><button type="button" id="item" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="myFunction()" value="<?php echo 'R-' . $id_print ;?>"> <i class="icon-cart"></i></button></center></td> 
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

After printing the results in the table, I need to get two values after clicking on a button.
I need to get those values from an input field (last column) user type number, and then click on that button.
For that I am using the following javascript

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
        var y = document.getElementById("item").value;

        window.location.href = "materijali.php?w1=" + x + "&w2=" + y
    }
</script>
```

By using the script above, I always get the values from the first row and redirect those values to the URL. 
I was wondering how to get values from the row where button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make few changes,

```
<table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered" style="width: 100%;">
<thead>
    <tr class="bg-teal-300">
        <th>Br.</th>
        <th>Materijal</th>
        <th>Tezina</th>
        <th>Boja</th>
        <th>Količina </th>
        <th><center><i class="ion-ios-cart-outline" style="font-size:18px; color:white;"><center></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php while($r=$q->fetch()){ 
        $id_print = $r['Id'];
        ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?='R-'. $r['Id']?></td>
        <td><?=$r['Material']?> </td>
        <td><?=$r['Quantity']?></td>
        <td><?=$r['Color']?></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity" placeholder="" ></td>
        <td><center><button type="button" id="item" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="myFunction(this)" value="<?php echo 'R-' . $id_print ;?>"> <i class="icon-cart"></i></button></center></td> 
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

And in javascript:

```
<script>
function myFunction(object) {
var x = $(object).attr("value"); 
var y = $('#quantity', $(object).parent().parent().siblings()).val(); 
window.location.href = "materijali.php?w1=" + x + "&w2=" + y; 
}
</script>
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Does your page has jQuery?

Comment: Yes, <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/js/core/libraries/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: <td><center><button type="button" id="item" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="myFunction(this)" value="<?php echo 'R-' . $id_print ;?>"> <i class="icon-cart"></i></button></center></td> and in javascript function 
function myFunction(object) {
   var x = $(object).attr("value");
   var y = $('#quantity', $(object).parent().parent().siblings()).val();

    window.location.href = "materijali.php?w1=" + x + "&w2=" + y;
}

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Please update your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Done. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Its Duplicating the IDS. Id of the Input Filed "quantity" is duplicating. and Id of the Button "item" is duplicating.

Java Script is Considering the First ID's. every time its retrieving the first row.

Use the Different Id's For Each row. 
Its like item-(PHP Item-id) and quantity-(Php Item-Id)
So No Row is duplicating the Row Ids.

Answer (score 0):

Give your `input` a name `attribute` like `name="qty"`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity" placeholder="" name="qty" >
```

And from your `button` pass the reference of button like this

```
<button type="button" id="item" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="myFunction(this)" value="<?php echo 'R-' . $id_print ;?>">
```

And in javascript code get the value of `input` like this

```
function myFunction(btn)
{
 var value = btn.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("input[name='Name']").value
}
```

Comment: It does not work,  it does not pick any value. Once I pick up the values script needs to redirect to another url as well

Comment: Thanks, but it does not do anything. I got no results

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<tbody>
    <?php while($r=$q->fetch()){ 
        $id_print = $r['Id'];
        ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?='R-'. $r['Id']?></td>
        <td><?=$r['Material']?> </td>
        <td><?=$r['Quantity']?></td>
        <td><?=$r['Color']?></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity<?=$id_print?>" placeholder="" ></td>
        <td><center><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="myFunction(<?php echo 'R-' . $id_print ;?>,<?=$id_print?>)" > <i class="icon-cart"></i></button></center></td> 
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>


<script>
function myFunction(a,b) {
    var x = document.getElementById("quantity"+b).value;
    var y = a;

    window.location.href = "materijali.php?w1=" + x + "&w2=" + y
}
</script>
```